# Nginx passenger rails

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

On a EC2 with ubuntu 14.04 with nginx/passenger/rails came with this log on nginx:

> App 31063 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/ruby:
>   Permission denied (13)
>
> App 31065 stderr: /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh: line 3: rbenv: command not
>   found

**nginx conf is:**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
       listen 80;
        server_name teste.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/teste/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        access_log  logs/access.log;


        location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }


       error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
       client_max_body_size 4G;
       keepalive_timeout 10;

            }


}
```

**someone cloud give some light? thank's**

Answer (score 1):

You have not set `passenger_ruby` correctly.

```
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby;
```

This is meant to be set to the Ruby binary itself. But you have set it to a directory.

Change it to the location of your `ruby` interpreter.

Comment: thank's @michael-hampton but show the same: ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Again, that's a directory, not a copy of the `ruby` program.

Comment: but with which ruby show: /usr/local/bin/ruby so, i tried to find and did not find the ruby interpreter on ubuntu

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/ruby` would be correct, then.